# Set section and aside to expand automatically with main tag

Tags: html, css

I want to set inner-section and sidebar to some min-height and then they should expand vertically along with `main` tag.

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <section class="innersection">
            some content
            </section>
            <aside class="sidebar">
            snas
           </aside>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

CSS code :

```
main{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
}

.innersection{
float:left;
width:94%;
display:inline;
}
.sidebar{
float:right;
width:5%;
display:inline;
}
```

I tried it but it is not working. With inner-section and sidebar the height of `main` tag is not increasing. I have attached a image of the page [image: img].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly, you want `.innersection` and `.sidebar` to both have the same height, and both take the height of it's parent?

If so, you could display `main > section` as a table and the both children as table-cells.

```
main{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
}
main > section {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.innersection{
    width:94%;
    height: 800px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.sidebar{
    width:5%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/er3220L8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make your main position as absolute

```
main{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
}

.innersection{
float:left;
width:94%;
display:inline;
border:1px solid black;
}
.sidebar{
float:right;
width:5%;
display:inline;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvj5bm0k/1/)